# Find ratio of categorical variable in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df in which I have customer ID, and theier purhcase either at discount or regular price. I want to find cutomer ratio of thier purchase.

```
Customer Price_Type
 1        Discount
 1        Discount
 1        Discount
 1        DealerNet        
 1        DealerNet 
 1        DealerNet 
 2        DealerNet 
 2        DealerNet 
 2        DealerNet
 2        DealerNet
```

Expected Output is:

```
Customer  at_Dicount at_DealerNet
  1          50              50
  2           0              100
```

I tried groupby function but did not get what exactly I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize`, multiple by `100` and data cleaning - [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df['Customer'], df['Price_Type'], normalize='index')
         .mul(100)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
   Customer  DealerNet  Discount
0         1       50.0      50.0
1         2      100.0       0.0
```